# HTML Form not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form to create a new Category(new.html.erb) in my rails app, which has GET link in another view(panel.html.erb).

POST is working fine when i directly enter the url in browsers address bar to create a new category, but whenever i try to access the new category form(new.html.erb) from panel.html.erb through a link, the form is rendered but data is not submitting.
I have defined the routes as

```
get '/catagories/new'
```

for new category form and

```
post 'catagories/create'
```

for creating a new category. I am new to Rails and really don't understand what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default rails form submits to `/categories` rather than to `categories/create` (Restfull routes). You should have your routes to be defined as a resources:

```
resources :categories
```

If you want to override the default (not recommended for a beginner), you can do this in your form_tag:

```
<%= form_for @category, url: '/categories/create' %>
```

Note however that this will make it harder to change this url later (as there are now two places to change, routes and form). You should then use named route:

```
post 'catagories/create', as: :create_category
```

and then:

```
<%= form_for @category, url: create_category_path %>
```